# How to show that two expressions are the symbolically the same

Tags: simplifying-expressions

The following two expressions are the same when checked numerically.

```
fun1[x_, y_] = 
  1/4 (Sqrt[(1 - y)/(
      4 + y (-4 + (1 - 2 x)^2 y))] (2 - y + Sqrt[
        4 + y (-4 + (1 - 2 x)^2 y)]) - 
     2 ((-1 + 2 x) y + Sqrt[
        4 + y (-4 + (1 - 2 x)^2 y)]) Sqrt[-(((-1 + y) (-2 + y + Sqrt[
          4 + y (-4 + (1 - 2 x)^2 y)])^2)/(4 - 
         4 y + ((-1 + 2 x) y + Sqrt[
           4 + y (-4 + (1 - 2 x)^2 y)])^2)^2)]);
fun2[x_, y_] = Sqrt[1 - y]/2;
```

However, *Mathematica* is not able to reduce `fun1[x,y]` to `fun2[x,y]`, with `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`. Is there any way of doing this simplification? Also  note  that $0\le x \le 1$ and $0\le y\le 1$.

Comment: Please write an *informative* title... one that actually deals with the nature of your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to cajole Mathematica into showing you that they are the same:

```
FullSimplify[Expand[fun1[x, y]^2], Assumptions -> {0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1}]
```

This gives (1-y)/4 and so the answer you desire is the square root of this, your function fun2[x,y].

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

These expressions **are indeed** symbolically the same. PowerExpand with the given asumptions shows it.

```
fun2[x, y] == fun1[x, y] // 
    PowerExpand[#, 
Assumptions -> {0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1}] & // Simplify

(*   True   *)
```

Answer (score 0):

The zero results of

```
Simplify[D[fun1[x, y] - fun2[x, y], x]]
```

and

```
Simplify[D[fun1[x, y] - fun2[x, y], y]]
```

and

```
Simplify[fun1[x, y] - fun2[x, y] /. {x -> 1/2, y -> 1/2}]
```

imply that these functions are identical on the square `{0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1}`.

Comment: fun1[x, y] - fun1[x, y] is always zero. Typo.

Comment: @Akku14: Thank you. Fixed.